# Reinstalling software giving Abort message

Tags: windows, uninstall

I installed a software and uninstalled it. When I am trying to reinstall, it showing up Abort message as,

> one or more newer versions of the product are already installed. An
>   upgrade is not applicapable. D:\FOLDER_NAME

I am using Windows Server 2008 Enterprise and installed software not there in control panel and also in uninstall folder of regedit.

Can you help me to clean software and folder(D:\FOLDER_NAME)

Comment: You could try http://www.revouninstaller.com/ " Revo Uninstaller Pro helps you to uninstall software and remove unwanted programs installed on your computer easily! Even if you have problems uninstalling and cannot uninstall them from "Windows Programs and Features (Add or Remove Programs)" control panel applet. ". There is a freeware version.

Comment: @DavidPostill Not allowed to install other softwares.....can you suggest any other possibilities

Comment: roll your system back to an earlier restoration point.

Comment: You could try manually cleaning the registry. Delete all keys containing <NameOfProgram>. Note serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Therefore, make sure that you follow these steps carefully. For added protection, back up the registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a problem occurs. For more information see [How to back up and restore the registry in Windows.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322756)

Comment: @DavidPostill It's not there in registry also

Comment: Finally the error got disappeared after removing Zero G Registry folder from Program files.....Thanks